# Save svg string to server from javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I would like to save my svg string:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ... and so on
```

on server.

```
$.ajax({
      url: saveTemplateUrl,
      type: "Get",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { "svg": svg },
      success: function (data) {
          alert("x");
      },
      error: function () {
      }
  });
```

I get jquery error: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation."
Svg string has 68739 characters. I'm not sure if this is some problem, but I guess not.
I have also tried with post, the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: use a POST request instead of a GET. I assume you hit the limit on the length of a GET request here.

Comment: you can use  data:{svg:document.getElementById('Layer_1').outerHTML}